# Set focus on widget in Perl/GTK2

Tags: perl, gtk

Is there a method to set focus on specified widget? (similar to Perl/Tk `$widget->focus;`) I can't find that method in Gtk.

Answer (score 1):

You want `$widget->grab_focus`

Comment: Unfortunately, `$widget->grab_focus` sets focus to the next widget from specified one.

Comment: Then you probably need to set `$widget->can_focus(1)` first